# waterfall with react native

Tags: react-native, waterfall

I want to use React native to layout a waterfall and the following is my current plan:

I wrap two flatlist inside a scrollview, when scrollview srolls to the position flatlist in, the scrollEnabe of scrollview is set to be false, so then the flatlist takes the scroll lead.

This plan is well done for a single flatlist, but now I want to use two flatlists and each of them has uncertain height items which is truly a waterfall, but here comes the problem:
How can I make two flatlists scroll at the same time ? As I know, the function scrollToOffset has delay compared to this scroll behavior.